# Localhost refuses to connect after upgrading to High Sierra OS

Tags: network, high-sierra, apache

I did upgrade to latest High Sierra, moved all old *.conf files like httpd.conf~previous to be in use. Checking config works fine:

```
sudo apachectl -t
Syntax OK
```

ping of 127.0.0.1 works as expected, server config file is

```
SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

when I try to open localhost or try

```
curl -I -L localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

I'm keep getting refuse, did I miss something? I really will appreciate any help.

I did not change port in httpd.conf from 8080 to 80, because on 8080 I have ngnix listening.

Even when I do ping of some of virtual hosts I have defined it works I mean ping get data because it use 127.0.0.1, but if I try to open page in browser I get connection refused.

Comment: Your question (+ details) is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)! Apache & virtual hosts & macOS and X contain so many variables, that it is impossible to answer your question with the given details. Also: *I did not change port in httpd.conf from 8080 to 80, because on 8080 I have ngnix listening.* sounds illogical.

Comment: I use all latest instance apache 2.4, High Sierra is OS, on Sierra all worked fine...in the mean time I also removed all nginx instances, but what is funny on localhost:8080 in browser from some reason I see ngnix welcome page...